# Data Changes in android wear app not reflecting in mobile app

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I have added increment counter in wear module and trying to pass the incremented value to the mobile module. Even though , I receive "successfully sent" response from the wear module(through google API sendmessage() called inside a service), the message is not being received by Listener service(extends Wearable listenerService) in the mobile module.I have added following intent filters for the mobile listener service,

```
        <service android:name=".ListenerService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.DATA_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.CAPABILITY_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.CHANNEL_EVENT" />
            <data android:scheme="wear" android:host="*" android:pathPrefix="/prefix" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I am incrementing count everytime and but still no response,Everything is fine till it is dispatched from the wearable.Any suggestions would be great.

The following things I have verified,

- Both of the modules package names and application Ids are identical.

  I am running the wear app on emulator hence, verified  that
  emulatore is already connected to mobile through Android wear app.

  Able to send notifications from mobile to wear app.

  Made sure count in wear app is changing everytime I send it to
  mobile app.

  No signing key difference possiblity as I both the modules are run
  as debug builds.

  Made sure both the URI paths are same for shared data(count).

Comment: i am unable to send data from phone also, and not even to wear... did you find any solution??